# JS - Calculate an interval for a given number

Tags: javascript

I am trying to generalize the following function that I have implemented:

```
/**
 * Calculates an interval for the given age.
 *
 * @memberof module:Users/Functions
 * @function getAgeInterval
 * @param {number} age - The age of the user.
 * @param {number} [minimumAge=18] - The minimum age.
 * @param {number} [range=10] - The range.
 * @throws {Error} The given age must be greater or equal than the minimum age.
 * @returns {string} The age interval.
 */
export default (age, minimumAge = 18, range = 10) => {
  if (age < minimumAge) {
    throw new Error(
      "The given age must be greater or equal than the minimum age.";
    );
  }

  const start = Math.floor((age - 1) / range) * range + 1;
  const end = start + range - 1;
  const interval = `${Math.max(start, minimumAge)}-${end}`;

  return interval;
};
```

Basically, in this method, I group the age of my users using a **minimum age** and a **range**. Here is an example:

```js
const getAgeInterval = (age, minimumAge = 18, range = 10) => {
  if (age < minimumAge) {
    throw new Error(
      "The given age must be greater or equal than the minimum age."
    );
  }

  const start = Math.floor((age - 1) / range) * range + 1;
  const end = start + range - 1;
  const interval = `${Math.max(start, minimumAge)}-${end}`;

  return interval;
};

//
// MAIN
//

for (let age = 18; age < 100; age += Math.round(Math.random() * 10)) {
  console.log(`${age}: ${getAgeInterval(age)}`);
}
```

For now, the method is only working for "ages". But I suppose it is possible to make it work with any type of numbers, (i.e. the total followers counter of a user).

Users might have different number of followers, and I need to group it reusing the method I implemented. The output should look like:

```
0: "0-10"

100: "11-100"

999: "101-1000"

1117: "1001-10000"
9999: "1001-10000"

15201: "10001-100000";

1620620: "1000001-10000000"
```

As you can see, the only difference, in order to make it work, is the "dynamic" range. If you take a look at the output, the range goes from 10 to millions.

Any ideas? Any generic implementation to allow dynamic ranges?

---

### UPDATE

Here is the generic method:

```js
const calculateInterval = (counter, minimumCounter = 0, range = 10) => {
  if (counter < minimumCounter) {
    throw new Error(
      "The given counter must be greater or equal than the minimum counter."
    );
  }

  const start = Math.floor((counter - 1) / range) * range + 1;
  const end = start + range - 1;
  const interval = `${Math.max(start, minimumCounter)}-${end}`;

  return interval;
};

//
// MAIN
//

const counters = [0, 100, 999, 1117, 9999, 15201, 1620620];

counters.forEach((totalFollowers) => {
  console.log(`${totalFollowers}: ${calculateInterval(totalFollowers)}`);
});

//
// Q: HOW DO I MAKE THE RANGE DYNAMIC (BASED ON THE AMOUNT OF FOLLOWERS)?
//
```

OUTPUT MUST BE:

```
0: "0-10"

100: "11-100"

999: "101-1000"

1117: "1001-10000"
9999: "1001-10000"

15201: "10001-100000";

1620620: "1000001-10000000"
```

Comment: What's the actual question here? The range is dynamic already

Comment: @SeanMcCafferty I don't know how to auto-calculate the range based on the amount of followers.

Comment: "Age" and "follower count" are both numbers. What's the issue you're having?

Comment: @evolutionxbox take a look at the update

Comment: By *dynamic*, do you mean *logarithmic*? That is when ranges are not incremented but multiplied by a fixed amount compared to the previous interval.

Comment: @FZs yes, I meant that, sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a logarithmic scale. In this case, the interval is not incremented but multiplied by the range in each step.

You can find the beginning of the range by raising `r` to the floor of the `r`-base logarithm of `n-1`, where `r` is the range and `n` is the number.

To get the edge cases right though, you need to make some adjustments (add one to the start of the range, add a default for values smaller or equal to the range, etc):

```js
const baseNlog = (base, x) => Math.log(x) / Math.log(base)

const logarithmicInterval = (n, range = 10) => {

  if(n <= range)
    return `0-${range}`
    
  const start = range ** Math.floor(baseNlog(range, n-1));
  const end = start * range;
  const interval = `${start + 1}-${end}`;

  return interval;
};


//
// MAIN
//

console.log([
  0,
  1,
  10,
  11,
  100,
  999,
  1117,
  9999,
  15201,
  1620620
].map(e => `${e}: ${logarithmicInterval(e)}`))
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can simply do is counting the number of digit in the number and creating your range using this.

For the low range it will be `10 ** (nbDigits - 1) + 1` (or 0 if the number is 0)

For the high range it will be `10 ** (nbDigits)`

```js
const calculateInterval = (number, minimumCounter = 0) => {
  if (number < minimumCounter) {
    throw new Error(
      "The given counter must be greater or equal than the minimum counter."
    );
  }

  const nbDigits = number > 0 ? (number - 1).toString().length : 1
  const start = number > 0 ? 10**(nbDigits - 1) + 1 : 0
  const end = 10 ** (nbDigits)
  
  const interval = `${Math.max(start, minimumCounter)}-${end}`;

  return interval;
};

//
// MAIN
//

const counters = [0, 100, 999, 1117, 9999, 15201, 1620620];

counters.forEach((totalFollowers) => {
  console.log(`${totalFollowers}: ${calculateInterval(totalFollowers)}`);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

One simple implementation could use a switch block to return a range string based on the length of the passed number.

Working snippet:

```js
console.log(getRange(100))
console.log(getRange(999))

function getRange(num) {

numdigits= parseInt(num-1).toString().length;

switch(numdigits) {
  case 1:
    return "0..10"
  case 2:
    return "11..100"
  case 3:
    return "101..1000"
  case 4:
    return "1001..10000"
  case 5:
    return "10001..100000"
  case 6:
    return "100001..1000000"
  case 7:
    return "1000001..10000000"
  default: 
    return "too large"
} 

}// end function
```

Another approach could build the string by catenating zeros to the upper and lower limits in a loop iterating the length of the passed number times.

Like this:

```js
console.log(getRange(100))
console.log(getRange(999))

function getRange(num) {

numdigits= parseInt(num-1).toString().length;

if (numdigits == 0) {return "0..10"} 
else {
return `1${"0".repeat(numdigits-2)}..1${"0".repeat(numdigits)}`;
}

} // end function
```